# Trying to activate hyper-v after ssd clone

Tags: windows-10, ssd, hyper-v

On my windows 1o machine, i am unable to enable the hyper-v services. After I enable it and restart the machine, the start screen says that the changes will be reverted again. (This is when i try to enable it as windows features [image: windows features]).

After restart, the event viewer shows me problems enabling all hyper-v services

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Servicing" Guid="{BD12F3B8-FC40-4A61-A307-B7A013A069C1}" /> 
  <EventID>11</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>1</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-11-08T19:50:29.554418200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>222</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="2316" ThreadID="2372" /> 
  <Channel>Setup</Channel> 
  <Computer>yyyyyyyy</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <UserData>
- <CbsUpdateChangeState xmlns="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/setup_provider">
  <UpdateName>Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services</UpdateName> 
  <PackageIdentifier>Microsoft-Hyper-V-ClientEdition-Package</PackageIdentifier> 
  <ErrorCode>0x800f0922</ErrorCode> 
  <Client>Windows Optional Component Manager</Client> 
  </CbsUpdateChangeState>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

I used to be able to activate hyper-v running windows 8.1 on the same hardware, then I switched to xamarin programming for a while, and had to disable it.
Since then I updated to windows 10 and also cloned my 256mb ssd to a 512mb ssd.

The internet says, when cloning a drive, one shoukd run

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

On my maschine, this outputs

```
Falscher Parameter.
```

It's a german os, so it probably means

```
Invalid parameter.
```

After a restart, and running bcdedit without a parameter i get the following output

```
Windows-Startladeprogramm
-------------------------
Bezeichner              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {b6488dab-f6aa-11e2-91cc-edc2952261ad}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {b6488da9-f6aa-11e2-91cc-edc2952261ad}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
Falscher Parameter.
```

So `Falscher Parameter.` (`Invalid parameter.`) keeps showing up.

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you verfied Hyper-V is an installed feature?  Just to verify, your running Windows 10 Professional, correct?

Comment: It sounds like the "invalid parameter" is actually `{current}` not `hypervisorlaunchtype`

Comment: @Ramhound when trying to enable the feature, i have to restart, this is when windows tells me it has to revert the changes, and after restart, the features are unchecked again. yes, windows 10 pro

Comment: but {current} is the correct parameter...

Comment: You said you were unable to enable/start the services....

Comment: Let us verify: `bcdedit /set {current} description "Windows 10A"`; after you do `bcdedit /export C:\SAVEDBCD`

Comment: `bcdedit /set {current} description "Windows 10A"
Falscher Parameter.`

then

`bcdedit

...
description             Windows 10A`

so the update for current is ok

Comment: If you cannot even edit the description of the entry something serious is going on.  Export it to two different files.  You are going to manually modify one of them, and load the one you modify, with `bcdedit /import c:\savedbcd`.  Within WinRE, run `bootrec /rebuildallbcd`, be sure your other SSD, is not connected.

Comment: You can also skip {current} it looks like and simply run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` per Microsoft's own documentation on Windows 10 BCDEdit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48203/discussion-between-ramhound-and-esskar).

Comment: disable your Av suite and try again to activate Hyper-V. If this doesn't help, share the logs from C:\windows\logs\CBS so that I can analyze what is wrong

Comment: thanks everyone. When i come home tonight, my windows automatically updated to 'Funktionsupdate für Windows 10 – Version 1607'. Now Hyper-V works as expected.

Comment: ok, post this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it seems that my windows was somehow broken.
I updated to 'Windows 10 – Version 1607'. After that, Hyper-V works as expected. The update may repaired some windows files/settings. `bcdedit` no longer show the `falscher parameter` error. So maybe reparing windows will fix this problem in general.